# Generics getting Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Tags: java, generics

I am getting the error Syntax error on token "extends", , expected for the below code.

```
class Driver<T>{

}

class DriverDetails<T extends Driver<T extends Object>> {

}
```

Comment: use this `? extends ...`

Comment: You probably want to use two different letters for the two type parameters.

Comment: `T extends Object` belongs to `Driver<T>` (-> `Driver<T extends Object>`), not to `DriverDetails`.

Comment: ? extends is working fine but why T extends is not working?

Comment: Well, when you say `T extends`,  you're defining what types `T` can be.  Then you're saying `T extends` a second time.  That is, you're changing your mind and giving a different definition of what `T` can be.  So `T extends` isn't a problem per se; it's the fact that you're saying it twice.

Comment: class Driver<T>{

}

class DriverDetails<T extends Driver<? extends Object>> {

}

Comment: Can you explain me in detail why the coding is working fine after replacing T with ?.

Comment: Because you're no longer defining `T` twice.  My previous comment explains it all.